# PHP round crazy bug

Tags: php, floating-point

```
<?php
    $last_percent = 0;
    $as = array("110.800002098083",  "30", "36.1499996185303", "11", "13", "13.9899997711182", "74.5200042724609", "13.9899997711182");
    $t = 304.46000552177;
    foreach($as as $a) {
        $last_percent += round($a*100/$t, 2);
    }
    var_dump( $last_percent);
    $last_percent = 100 - $last_percent;
    var_dump( $last_percent);
?>
```

why results is 0.33000000000001? why it only happen with 100 and 99? if i use $last_percent = 90 - $last_percent;
results is -9.67

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php <- has a big red box with a warning. read it.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that float values are not perfect. Sometimes, depending on your system setup, there are errors.

The longer answer is that float values aren't exact representations of numerical values, they are approximations that - in most cases - are good enough.  The problem is that sometimes the value you want will fall into a region where float doesn't work perfectly, and you get rounding errors like these.

This is why systems that rely on precise values, like financial applications, don't use floats.  They use special purpose high-precision types, or else represent dollars and cents with two separate integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point calculations are not reliable when you need 100% precision. PHP documentation has official warning about it here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php and you should use arbitrary precision math functions or gmp functions if you need high precision of calculations.

Comment: *"PHP is unrealiable when you work with floating point numbers."* ... PHP **is not** unreliable, *floating point math* is inexact.

Comment: sorry, true, it's not PHP, it's floating point problem

Comment: @ElenaSharovar - then what about [editing your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13061289/edit) to say so?

Answer (score 0):

Why floating point numbers aren't exact:

They treat decimals as a compound of binary fractions. 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...

Not all numbers can be represented perfectly by this, so it simply gives you it's 'best try'.